# Redirect Uri on azure ad b2c opens the browser with an error

Tags: flutter, azure-ad-b2c

I have a cross platform flutter app which I am going to safeguard with Azure ad b2c authentication. This is the way I got the redirect Uri set on the azure app registration portal and the flutter app. When I run the url directly on the browser it says the request does not contain a client_id paramter. Where should I be adding the client_id paramter on my endpoints?
[image]

Here how I am calling the policy in Flutter using the flutter_appAuth package. The code runs and opens the browser but I get an error on the browser saying the below [image]

Here is my flutter code-

```
 onPressed: () async {
                    FlutterAppAuth appAuth = const FlutterAppAuth();
                    final AuthorizationTokenResponse? result = await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
                      AuthorizationTokenRequest(
                        'client_id',
                        'com.test.azure_test/oauth2_redirect',
                        serviceConfiguration: const AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(authorizationEndpoint: 'https://testOrg.b2clogin.com/testOrg.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize', tokenEndpoint: 'https://testOrg.b2clogin.com/testOrg.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin/oauth2/v2.0/token'),
                        scopes: ['openid','offline_access','api'],
                      ),
                    );
                    print(result);
                  },
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment.***

In Azure AD B2C , I have Created an app registration

[image]

The redirect uri is given something like ***msauth://com.testapp***

[image]

As the app is registered in azure ad as well , as it was registered in Azure ad b2c app registration panel, tested what is wrong with the login.

I have tested it in browser using uri excluding msauth://
And only **com.testapp**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxf/oauth2/v2.0/token?
&client_id=xxxxx-9fa0-8exxxfb9bbc
&nonce=defaultNonce
&redirect_uri= com.testapp 
& grant_type=authorization_code
&scope=openid
&response_type=code
&prompt=login…
&scope=offline_access
&code=AwABAxxxxxxxxSUYBr
```

It is giving error as redirect uri is not correct.

[image]

Tried including msauth:// with slight mistake in uri

```
redirect_uri= msauth://com.testapp
```

[image]

Here the redirect URI is not matching the one which

- Please make sure the redirect uri is same as that you have registered in portal.
  Do recheck if the changes are saved after adding redirect URI

To resolve the issue, go to Azure AD B2C > **App Registrations** > find and ***search  the application with App ID in the error*** > Authentication blade, modify Redirect URI to
the one in the authentication request /uri or change the redirect uri in the auth url that is present in code matching portal's.

```
  &redirect_uri= msauth://com.testapp
```

[image]

Also check [flutter-azure-authentication-with-ad-b2c | by Jayesh | Flutter Community | Medium](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-azure-authentication-with-ad-b2c-8b76c81dd48e)

Comment: Hello Kavya, I tried your steps, I still get an error.